# Android multi module project

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-multi-module

I'm trying to setup a multi-module project with bottom navigation fragments and hilt.
Is there any github project I can use to start my project faster?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start with android-architecture here in github:

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples